# Applying multiple styles on Textblock populated by Data binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a `<TextBlock>` element that look like this,

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, StringFormat= 'Name: {0}'}"/>
```

Now how would I go if I wanted to have the first part as **Bold** style and the second one as *Italic* style ,

eg.

**Name:** *Person's name*

At the moment using a style applies it on the result of my `StringFormat`.

Is there an easy way to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 2):

Use two Runs:

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run Text="Name:" FontWeight="Bold"/>
    <Run Text="{Binding Name}" FontStyle="Italic"/>
</TextBlock>
```